# Button to Load more data to DatagridView, more than 20000 register C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a Big doudt.

I'm trying to load my data with this code:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Login.conectData);
        con.Open();
        DataSet dsFabricantes = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter daFabricantes = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM 
        Fabricantes", con);
        dsFabricantes.Clear();

        //prencher a tabela
        daFabricantes.Fill(dsFabricantes, "Fabricantes");
        tabelaFabricantes.DataSource = dsFabricantes;
        tabelaFabricantes.DataMember = "Fabricantes";


        //para mudar o que está escrito no cabeçalho das colunas

        tabelaFabricantes.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Nome do 
         Fabricante";
        tabelaFabricantes.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Observações";

        con.Close();
        tabelaFabricantes.ClearSelection();
```

I Want to make a button to load more register in my datagridView. Onload of the app I am changing just 100 register. My question is:

**How can I add a button to onClickbutton this button, my dataGrideView, Load more 100 Register and so on and so on** ?

little Help
thank you 
Bráulio José

Comment: Saying something like *"Please Help me, is Very urgently"* isn't going to get people to jump to help you; it makes your post look more like a plea, and the users here are volunteers using their **own** time (in fact, pleas often are more likely to be ignored by users). On topic: If you want more than 100 rows, why are you using `TOP 100`?

Comment: Start with WPF as it has virtualization.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Have you tried adding a button and got stuck? If so please show your code.

Comment: @Larnu I put 100 because I dont want to load every 20.000 register. the app get much slowly.

Comment: Hi @sr28 I have my button  but I didn't put any code there because is for that I came to ask for Help

Comment: Adding code helps explain your problem and identify specifically where you're having issues. Otherwise it just looks like your asking people to do your work for you.

Comment: I am new with C# but is amost the same as JAVA

Comment: @sr28 I just want some ideia to how can I do it or what I will need, to start my solution and show to everyone and share opinion

Comment: Is this web forms?

Comment: I am usin visual studio 2013, Windows Form

Comment: Use skip and take to paginate over your results, never loading much more than what the user is looking at.

Comment: I will try the paginate. I was studing other solution, I will try paginate. I will be back whan I finished to show if it works or no

Comment: @CarloBos i disagree with your advice given the data access strategy in use

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dynamically adapt your SqlDataAdapter() call.

First set some global variables on page/formOnLoad method

```
global int startRow = '1';
global int maxColRank = testMaxRows();


#set left button active = false
leftButton.Active = false;
```

To do this, class your DataGridViewLoader separately to accept no parameters. Name the class mySqlGridViewLoaderClass()
at the beginning of this class input these values:

```
string MaximumRows = '100';
string StartRowIndex = StartRow.ToString();
```

In the SQL connector for this DataGridViewLoader, use a query similar to

```
SELECT colRank, col1, col2
FROM
   (SELECT col1, col2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS colRank
    FROM Fabricantes
   ) AS rowNumQuery
WHERE colRank > <i>StartRowIndex</i> AND
      colRank <= (<i>StartRowIndex</i> + <i>MaximumRows</i>
   )
```

Your class should perform DataGridView loading operation, then return a second scalar value for MAX(colRank).

```
#new connector
SqlDataAdapter daFabricantes = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Max(colRank) FROM 
    (SELECT max(colRank)
FROM
   (SELECT col1, col2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS colRank
    FROM Fabricantes
   ) AS rowNumQuery
WHERE colRank > <i>StartRowIndex</i> AND
      colRank <= (<i>StartRowIndex</i> + <i>MaximumRows</i>
   ))", con2);
int mr = (Int32) con2.ExecuteScalar();
return mr;
```

class a second SQL connector loader to test max Rows and return a scalar value. name the class testMaxRows()
In the sql connector, use a query similar to:

```
 Select count(col1) DIST from fabricantes;
```

Return the count to the tr variable. The last 2 lines of maxRows class should be:

```
int tr = (Int32) con.ExecuteScalar();
return tr;
```

In your form designer, create a button for '<' and '>'
Set < button to inactive. > button to active

In the '<' ButtonOnClick() event:

```
rightButton.Active = true;
if (StartRow != '1') 
{
     StartRow -= 100;

     # your class expects a return value, so we'll initialize one
     int mr = (Int32) mySqlGridViewLoaderClass();

     if (StartRow == 1) 
     {
         leftButton.Active = false;
     }
}
```

In the '>' ButtonOnClick() event:

```
leftButton.Active = true;

StartRow += 100;
int maxRank = (Int32) mySqlGridViewLoaderClass();

if ( maxRank >= maxColRank)
{
    rightButton.Active = false;

}
```